# is there a way to save the data from wordcloud or comparison.cloud

Tags: r, shiny, quanteda

I'm trying to save the data that is used in `wordcloud` or `comparison.cloud` (or quanteda verison `textplot_wordcloud`) but I'm noticing when I save it to a variable (`t1 = wordcloud(x)`), it saves as `NULL`.

My goal of this is to get the unique or key words for a group and build an interactive plot in Shiny where when a word is clicked on it displays the output of `kwic()` and shows the context of the keyword.

```
ui <- fluidPage(# App title ----
                theme = shinytheme('flatly'),
                titlePanel("Employtics"),

                # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                sidebarLayout(
                  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # Input: Select a file ----
                    fileInput("FileInput", "Choose file"),

                    # Input: Horizontal Line ----
                    tags$hr(),


                    uiOutput('textField'),
                    uiOutput('docIdField')
                  ),

                  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(     tabPanel(
                          'Word Clouds',
                          fluidRow(plotOutput(
                            'wordcloud', width = "100%", height = '800'))         )
            )
            ))

    output$wordcloud = renderPlot({
        d1 = dCorp()

        withProgress(message = 'Building Wordclouds',
                     detail = 'This may take a while...',expr = 0)
                       if (is.null(input$selectGroup2)) {
                         textplot_wordcloud(
                           d1,
                           max.words = 15
                         )

                       }
                       else{
                         textplot_wordcloud(d1,
                                            comparison = T,
                                            max.words = 15,
                                            title.size = 1)
                       }

      })
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, `textplot_wordcloud()` does not return a data object.

Suggestions:

1. Use `textstat_keyness()` to get the differentially occurring words by group. This returns a data.frame that would work for your purposes. You could then use this as input for your plot, and possibly for **wordcloud2**. (See next suggestion.)
2. Consider the **wordcloud2** package, which also has Shiny (and interactive support). See https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1218 for a discussion.

Comment: Interesting. I see the post on issue 1218, but wordcloud2 doesn't have a comparison feature right? Have you ever seen interactive wordclouds that allow clicking on a word and passing that word and docvars through kwic?